# XSLT: Get nth occurence of element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to get the nth occurence of an element C in my XML (across different parents)

**Input:**

```
<TEST>
<A>
    <B>*</B>
    <C>Text1</C> (#1)
</A>
<A>
    <B>*</B>
</A>
<A>
    <B>/</B>
    <C>Aaaa</C> (#2)
</A>
<A>
    <B>/</B>
    <C>Text2</C> (#3)
</A>
</TEST>
```

**Desired result:** get 2nd  Element would yield "Aaaa"

**I tried:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sch="http://sap.com/xi/ME" xmlns:me="http://sap.com/xi/ME" xmlns:gdt="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal/GDT" xmlns:meint="http://sap.com/xi/MEINT" xmlns:demand="http://www.sap.com/me/demand" xmlns:common="http://www.sap.com/me/common">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/TEST/A/descendant::C[2]"/>        
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I get this to work?

Found this example but I can't get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280116

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt does not work because the 1st `A` element does not have a 2nd `C` descendant.

To select the 2nd `C` element in the entire document, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/descendant::C[2]"/>
```

or (same thing):

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//C)[2]"/>
```

To restrict the selection to `C` elements that are within the given hierarchy, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(/TEST/A/C)[2]"/>
```

Comment: I have my modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (notice the parenthesis):

```
<xsl:value-of select="(/TEST/A/descendant::C)[2]"/>
```

For an explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008925